# Stanford CoreNLP Simple API Error

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Im just trying to run a simple example to get started with CoreNLP from [here](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/simple.html). I have added coreNLP and models 3.6 to my pom.xml. I have also added com.google.protobuf(3.0.0-beta-3) to my pom as well.

This what my code looks like:

```
 Document doc = new Document("add your text here! It can contain multiple sentences.");
        for (Sentence sent : doc.sentences()) {  // Will iterate over two sentences
            // We're only asking for words -- no need to load any models yet

            System.out.println("The second word of the sentence '" + sent + "' is " + sent.word(1));
            // When we ask for the lemma, it will load and run the part of speech tagger
            System.out.println("The third lemma of the sentence '" + sent + "' is " + sent.lemma(2));
            // When we ask for the parse, it will load and run the parser
            System.out.println("The parse of the sentence '" + sent + "' is " + sent.parse());
            // ...
        }
```

And here's the exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   edu.stanford.nlp.util.ArrayCoreMap.keySetNotNull()Ljava/util/Set;     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ProtobufAnnotationSerializer.toProtoBuilder(ProtobufAnnotationSerializer.java:377)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ProtobufAnnotationSerializer.toProtoBuilder(ProtobufAnnotationSerializer.java:332)
>     at edu.stanford.nlp.simple.Document.sentences(Document.java:480)    at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.simple.Document.sentences(Document.java:499)

UPDATE:

I just downgraded protobuf to 2.6.1 and still the same issue. Here what my pom looks like:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <classifier>models</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple API doesn't work with Proto v.3. It was compiled with 2.6.1, though anything in version 2 should work.

Comment: i just tried it with 2.6.1 and still the same error

Comment: Your example says "2.6.0" not "2.6.1"...also it is important you use 2.6.1 and make sure nothing else is pulling in a different version of protobuf because it won't work with other versions...@gabor btw I tried this with 2.5 a while back and I think it failed so I think its key to use 2.6.1, not positive about that though...

Comment: it turns out one of the maven assemblies was conflicting and causing this issue. I started with a clean project and it worked!